# Sync Azure deployment using PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

When an Azure website is configured to deploy from Dropbox you can deploy a website by clicking the 'sync' button from the DEPLOYMENTS 'tab'.

[image]

Is there an equivalent method of doing this using PowerShell?